# multiple default optional values

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, optional-parameters, default-parameters

I have a function that accepts two integers with default value, is there a way to allow the caller of the functions to pass as many parameters as he wants? (first but not second, second but not first, both).
example:

```
void do_something(int first = 0, int second = 0);

int main()
{
   do_something(1); // first - how to declare it's the first argument
   do_something(1); // second
   do_something(1,1); 
   do_something();
   return 0; // I want to allow all those options
}
```

Comment: `do_something(1); // second` - this is not possible. You have to pass default parameter explicitly: `do_something(0, 1);`. The rest of them is fine.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen you could write this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use another wrapper inline function

```
   void DoSomething(int f = 0 , int s = 0)
   {}
   void inline DoSomethingS(int s = 0)
   {DoSomething(0 , s);}
```

If the user wants to send the second and leave the first optional he'll use the DoSomething+options in this case DoSomethingS.

Comment: Declare first and then implement without default arguments :)

Comment: I missed the trailing S, sorry.

Comment: @PaulSanders np so you got it working ?

Comment: Your solution looks fine, yes.

Comment: So mark the V next to my answer

Comment: I am not the OP

Comment: @PaulSanders oh sorry